# Como obtener registros de una tabla pivote en Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, ajax

Tengo una consulta, como puedo obtener los registro de actividades que tiene el objeto project, en la relacion muchos a muchos? en la tabla pivot tiene los campos id_project, id_activity, no tiene datos extras en la pivot, pero quisiera obtener la relacion muestre el nombre de cada actividad por proyecto.

Este es el modelo de la tabla projects

```
class Project extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'summary', 'long', 'width', 'thickness', 'rows', 'tube', 'progress', 'start_date_p', 'expected_date_p', 'end_date_p', 'quantity', 'slug', 'status','order_id'];      
          
    //relacion muchos a muchos
    public function activities(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Activity')
                    ->withTimestamps();;

    }
```

Este es el modelo de la tabla activity

```
class Activity extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['name','priority','start_date','expected_date','end_date','status','stage_id','user_id'];

    //relacion muchos a muchos
    public function projects(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Project')
                    ->withTimestamps();

    }

}
```

Este es mi controller donde obtengo el project por id enviado y usando el objeto project queria obtener todas las actividades con su nombre segun la relacion en la tabla pivot .
Estaba probando asi llamando a la relacion - $activities = $project->activities;

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        try{
            $project = Project::find($id);
            $activities = $project->activities;
            
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Hubo un problema en obtener los datos del proyecto', 'error' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }        

        return response()->json(['data' => $project]);
    }
```